# Adding multiple values in a query parameter in Access 2007

Tags: ms-access, parameters, ms-access-2007, query-string, multiple-value

I have a query in Access that has a parameter for `Customer ID`.

I've set up the parameter like this: `Field: CustID Table:cutomer Criterial:[Choose CustID]`. However, currently, I'm only able to enter a single value into the parameter.

**Is there a way to enter multiple values into the query parameter?**

Unfortunately, I can't use forms. I am extracting data based on a value to an excel workbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using example from [Microsoft's site](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/100131) I'd suggest you use example 1 - seeing as you seem to indicate VBA is not an option

This should give you the helpful prompt to type in all valid CustIDs separated by a comma, or just leave blank so get them all

```
  Field: InStr([Cust IDs separated by commas, Blank=All],[CustID])
  Criteria:  > 0 Or Is Null
  Show: False
```

> Example: When prompted enter 1,2,3 - to get records with those
>   customer IDs

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Your Microsoft link is broken. Would you mind fixing it?